# Creating an array of characters in a for loop

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C and was testing some of its functions.
When I try to create an array of characters in a `for` loop, I get errors.

```
int i,j;
//Fixed
char fila0[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
char fila1[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
char fila2[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
char fila3[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
//The problem
char fila0[11],fila1[11],fila2[11],fila3[11];

for (i = 0; i<4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j<11; j++){
      switch(j){
      case 0:
         fila0[j] = struct_juego.tablero[i][j];
      break;
      case 1:
         fila1[j] = struct_juego.tablero[i][j];
      break;
      case 2:
         fila2[j] = struct_juego.tablero[i][j];
      break;
      case 3:
         fila3[j] = struct_juego.tablero[i][j];
      break;
      }
    }
}
```

`fila0` is full of strange characters now, they are not arrays characters
If I print `fila0` I get this

```
 ๗ ๘ ๙ ๚ 8∆ ∏
```

Comment: `arrar` has 99 elements. Of which row elements do you want to assign to `hi` (can hold 11 elements only)?

Comment: there is not only hi, they are other 8 chars but I dont think they are necesary to explain my problem

Comment: You get *what* errors? Compilation? Linker? Runtime?

Comment: no those kind of errors, in state of filling of 'O' and 'X' it fills with extrange simbols.

Comment: between `char hi[11]` and `array[9][11];` is a `,` and not a `;`? These arrays are not initialized, is that maybe the problem?

Comment: Then you have to provide more code, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). What you have now in no way helps. It's probable that you return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: So I have to initialize those arrays?

Comment: Yes. You must have to initialize `array`.

Comment: @user3120382: when they are not defined in the global scope, they are not initialized. Else they are initialized with 0.

Comment: I initialized both `array` and `hi` but it does not fix my problem

Comment: So the problem was the Devc++ compiler, it wasnt saving my compilation. I initialized `hi`and worked thaks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to show the output at every step:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  int i, j;
  char hi[11];
  char array[9][11]; //---- need to declare type.                                                                                                        

// Before initialization                                                                                                                               
  fprintf(stdout, "Before initialization, array contains: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
      fprintf(stdout, "%c ", array[i][j]);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "Before initialization, hi contains: \n");
  for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%c ", hi[j]);
  fprintf(stdout, "\n");

  for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) { // ----- initalize array.  Initializing hi also, to show difference later.                                                  
    hi[j] = 'a';
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
      array[i][j] = 65 + i;
  }
// After initialization                                                                                                                                
  fprintf(stdout, "initialized array contains: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
      fprintf(stdout, "%c ", array[i][j]);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "initialized hi contains: \n");
  for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%c ", hi[j]);
  fprintf(stdout, "\n");

  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
      hi[j] = array[i][j];
    }
  }

// After copying                                                                                                                                         
  fprintf(stdout, "After copying, array contains: \n");
  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
      fprintf(stdout, "%c ", array[i][j]);
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "After copying,  hi contains: \n");
  for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%c ", hi[j]);
  fprintf(stdout, "\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Initialization is missing.
Instead of doing:

```
char fila0[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
char fila1[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
char fila2[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
char fila3[11] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
```

do:

```
int len = 10;
char fila0[len];
char fila1[len];
char fila2[len];
char fila3[len];

for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
    fila0[i] = ' ';
    fila1[i] = ' ';
    fila2[i] = ' ';
    fila3[i] = ' ';
}
```

this way everythin get's initialized and it's more practical if you want to change the vector size.